# Why are perfect maps called perfect?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I have a research about perfect mapping and while researching I get curious about why it's called "perfect".
First the definition of perfect maps is :

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $p$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$ that is continuous, closed, surjective and such that $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact relative to $X$ for each $y$ in $Y$. Then p is known as a perfect map.

What makes such a map be perfect? Why is it called perfect? 
It'll be an interesting thing to add. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps "very good map" would be better!  A "perfect map" is essentially the "next best thing" to a homeomorphism.  It preserves many of the basic properties  of a topological space, such as local compactness, but not all of them.

Comment: Almost everything is "perfect" in mathematics: a perfect field, a perfect group, a perfect Lie algebra, etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know , but there is always a reason why it's called perfect . I'm not sure why for  prefect maps.

Comment: @user247327 I thought that but I wasn't sure, Thank you so much!

Comment: Look under the "examples and properties" heading in Wikipedia to understand the nomenclature a bit more. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_map